Composer autoload not autoloading
In short, the autogenerated autoload.php that Composer made for me isn't actually loading anything.
I have used Composer to install other people's projects before, but this is the first time I'm using it to manage dependencies in a project of my own.
Here is my composer.json. The names have been changed to protect the innocent:
{
    "name": "MyWorkplace/MyApp",
    "description": "A very cool doohickey.",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "wdmartin",
            "email": "redacted@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "onelogin/php-saml": "4.1.*"
    }
}

After putting in that require line, I ran composer update.  It downloaded the php-saml library, and also its dependency xmlseclibs, and generated an autoload.php file.
So I started work on the first file in the project, which looks like this:
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use OneLogin\Saml2\Settings;

// settings.php just creates the $settingsInfo array.
require_once('settings.php');

$settings = new Settings($settingsInfo, true);

Running the code yields the error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "OneLogin\Saml2\Settings" not found

The autoloader apparently didn't autoload the class definitions.
I tried saving the output of autoload.php to a variable and dumping it, which got me this:
object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader)#1 (11) {
  ["vendorDir":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  string(24) "/var/www/html/vendor"
  ["prefixLengthsPsr4":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["R"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\"]=>
      int(23)
    }
    ["O"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["OneLogin\"]=>
      int(9)
    }
  }
  ["prefixDirsPsr4":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(63) "/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../robrichards/xmlseclibs/src"
    }
    ["OneLogin\"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(58) "/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../onelogin/php-saml/src"
    }
  }
  ["fallbackDirsPsr4":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["prefixesPsr0":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fallbackDirsPsr0":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["useIncludePath":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["classMap":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Composer\InstalledVersions"]=>
    string(67) "/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../composer/InstalledVersions.php"
  }
  ["classMapAuthoritative":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["missingClasses":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["apcuPrefix":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  NULL
}

I can see the classes that it's supposed to load in there, but they don't exist. I tried running get_declared_classes(); at the end of the giant list of native PHP classes that always get loaded, I found the following three entries:
[215]=>
string(54) "ComposerAutoloaderInita5339d1e68f4fc243101898f7cd6b2b7"
[216]=>
string(29) "Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader"
[217]=>
string(68) "Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInita5339d1e68f4fc243101898f7cd6b2b7"

So the autoloader is definitely autoloading itself. But the OneLogin\Saml2 class is not in the list, nor is its dependency XMLSecLibs.
I tried manually editing the autoload files to make them tell me what they were doing by dumping a bunch of information along the way, but that didn't yield any usable information beyond verifying that the autoloader code does in fact have the correct paths to the folders for the libraries.
This is day two of banging my head against this. It's probably something very obvious, but I'm not seeing it. I could of course link in the code directly with something like require_once('vendor/onelogin/php-saml/src/Saml2/Settings.php');, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using Composer in the first place. Any advice would be appreciated.
Edit: Output of composer show
onelogin/php-saml      4.1.0 OneLogin PHP SAML Toolkit
robrichards/xmlseclibs 3.1.1 A PHP library for XML Security

Edit 2: Some debug output requested by AlexHowansky.  I ran this code:
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

print "Class exists?:\n";
var_dump(class_exists(\OneLogin\Saml2\Settings::class));

print "\n\nIs it in the array of declared classes?\n";
var_dump(in_array(\OneLogin\Saml2\Settings::class, get_declared_classes()));

It generated the following output:
Class exists?:
bool(false)


Is it in the array of declared classes?
bool(false)

Also, I checked all the file permissions in case the web server somehow didn't have permission to read it, and they look okay.

Your code works fine for me. What vesion of PHP? What version of composer? What's the output of composer show?

Check your composer.lock file to see if the package is listed there and if it's the correct 4.1.* version that you requested.

Where does your file live that has require_once('vendor/autoload.php');? This should be in the root of your project or the path will be incorrect.

@AlexHowansky PHP version is 8.3.4. Composer is 2.7.1. I edited the question to add the output of composer show, which lists the two required dependencies.

@apokryfos I checked composer.lock; it lists "version": "4.1.0" for php-saml, which is correct.

@DirkJ.Faber Yes, the path from the test file to autoload.php is correct.  The test file is in the root of the project, vendor is a subfolder.  The autoload.php file is definitely being included -- when I run get_declared_classes() I can see that it has added its own class. Just not the others. Which is so weird.

I can't reproduce, with the same versions. I'd start by reinstalling dependencies and regenerating the autoloader: rm -r composer.lock vendor && composer install

Try composer dump-autoload once, in order to update the auto-loader.

@AlexHowansky I ran rm -r composer.lock vendor and then re-ran composer install. Alas, no change.

@MartinZeitler I've run composer dump-autoload several times at this point, but it didn't help.

FWIW, this is on a RHEL 9 server with SE Linux running.  I checked /var/log/audit/audit.log in case it's some annoying SE Linux thing getting in the way, but tailing that log file and triggering the problem did not result in any new error messages there. So I don't think SE Linux is the culprit.

"But the OneLogin\Saml2 class is not in the list, nor is its dependency XMLSecLibs." Note that get_declared_classes() won't show classes that haven't been loaded yet, so this behavior is expected. What is the output of: require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); var_dump(class_exists(\OneLogin\Saml2\Settings::class)); var_dump(in_array(\OneLogin\Saml2\Settings::class, get_declared_classes()));

@AlexHowansky I've edited the question to add the output of that code.

What if you run it from the shell/CLI instead of the web server? php /var/www/html/test.php or whatever

I just ran it from CLI, and it worked!  No error message, and I tried adding a var_dump() to output $settings, and it contained all the stuff I would expect to see from successfully running the code.  So it's got to be something going wrong with Apache or the broader server environment.

It's a permissions issue, almost certainly. The user that ran the composer install (and thus, downloaded and created the local files) isn't the user that's running the web service. Or something thereabouts? Does RHEL use Suhosin maybe?

Somehow it's always the dang permissions. Sure would have been nice if there had been some kind of error message saying that it couldn't open the file, but there's nothing like that in the Apache logs, the PHP-FPM logs, or anywhere else.  Bah, humbug.
Thank you very much for helping diagnose the problem. I have an appointment to get my car's oil changed in about 15 minutes, so I'll have to circle back to this in a bit.

"would have been nice if there had been some kind of error message" There are, but Apache configurations generally disable them because you don't want to see them in production.

I'll have to go figure out how to enable those on this dev server then. In the mean time, running chmod -R 775 vendor fixed the problem. If you would like to submit an answer to that effect, I will happily accept it, with thanks.

Your configuration and code looks fine and works correctly for me on a RHEL 9 docker image. If you run:
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
var_dump(class_exists(\OneLogin\Saml2\Settings::class));
var_dump(in_array(\OneLogin\Saml2\Settings::class, get_declared_classes()));

And get:
bool(false)
bool(false)

Then it seems that the require is working correctly, else the script would abort at that point and never run the var_dump() calls. This would then suggest two conclusions: 1) your web server process can't read the files because they were downloaded by (and thus owned by) a different user and 2) you have error reporting disabled so you're not getting permission denied errors.
You could run a recursive permission change like chmod -R 775 vendor but this may be too permissive. Ideally, you want the files to be owned by a user other than the one running the web server process, and then set the permissions minimally to allow reading only. chmod -R 755 vendor is preferable.
To enable error reporting, load a page that runs the phpinfo() function. This will tell you what INI file the webserver process is using. See its contents for the values of:
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL

Note, if this is just a development server, I'm not sure I'd even bother with Apache, it (clearly) adds more trouble than it's worth. Check out the built-in web server which is more than sufficient for local development. I usually just add something like this to my composer.json file:
    "scripts": {
        "go": [
            "Composer\\Config::disableProcessTimeout",
            "php -S localhost:8000 -t public/"
        ]
    },

And then I can start a local server from the CLI with composer go, and I don't need anything more than PHP installed.
